# Can't get passed step 4 check out (Shipping method)

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

The problem i'm facing is that my webshop, which has 5 store views, gives problems with the check out procedure at step 4 (shipping methods) on the french and german store views. I checked all settings but everything is the same as the 3 other store views (Dutch, English and Italian). I get this message at step 4 (french and german store views): Entschuldigung, für diese Bestellungen stehen keine Auswahloptionen zur Verfügung. Bitte nehmen Sie direkt mit uns Kontakt auf! Which translates something like: We are sorry, for these orders there are no shipping options available.

Comment: It seams that you don't have any shipping methods available for that store. Either they are not enabled or they are not valid for that specific quote.

Answer (score 1):

first log in to admin panel and 
go to **system-> configuration-> shipping option and active any method**

if not working may be jquery issue.see your console is there any error log.if is any errors.use jQuery.noConflict()  mode